# Cannot Import DTSX files back into SQL Server 2008r2 Int Services after export and edit in VSPro2013

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-data-tools

I've carried out a lot of work here and want to be able to use my DTSX packages

But I get the version incompatibility and the Error message is specific

But there must be some way I can run my packages. They appear to not be able to be run from within VS2013 Pro editor

My question is, what do I need to install exactly to all allow me to execute these saved packages?

By asking here i can save time since there are many versions and many add ons etc

Comment: PS 2008r2 Management Studio does not let me EDIT packages, just export. Is this a license restriction or something, if so I am happy to upgrade and pay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - *how to run a SSIS 2008 package*?

There is a good overview [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1775/different-ways-to-execute-a-sql-server-ssis-package/), by Ashish Kumar Mehta of *MSSQTips*, on how to execute packages both remotely on the server or locally. Either way you need the *SQL Server Client Tools* installed from the *SQL Server* media (CD, image, etc.). There's no possibility of running a package locally from Management Studio or raw Visual Studio. You can run the package remotely through Management Studio only if that package was stored within the SQL Server. Theoretically, you *can* run a package in development mode via VS2013, see below.

Second - *how to modify a SSIS 2008 package*?

Unlike subsequent SQL Server (and SSIS) versions, with 2008 you couldn't just use your regular Visual Studio with a downloadable plugin. You had to install one *Business Intelligence Development Studio* (BIDS), a Visual Studio 2008 derivative (i.e. not a plugin) available on your SQL Server media. That's the way to go if you want to edit the package but also maintain its 2008 version. Otherwise, you're free to upgrade the package to Integration Services 2014 level by [several methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280546.aspx), and start hacking at it via Visual Studio 2013 with a downloadable [Data Tools - Business Intelligence](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/analysisservices/archive/2014/04/02/sql-server-data-tools-business-intelligence-for-visual-studio-2013-ssdt-bi.aspx) plug-in. Be advised, it's not possible to convert the package back to 2012 nor 2008 versions.

Comment: Thanks, i'd installed VS Pro 2013 and exported the package from 2008r2. I then loaded it up in Visual Studio 2013, did lots of work now cannot run it. Is there a way I can run it without installing a new SQL Server VErsion? you mentioned I can run a package in DEV mode in VS 2013, but I cannot see any option for this, only attach to process

Comment: If I could just run the package i'm editing now in SQL Server Data Tools for 2013 i'd be OK

Comment: @John - you can run the package from VS (with the Data Tools BI plugins), see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137806.aspx) (more general text on debugging [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137880(v=sql.105).aspx)); one of the other options is [DTEXECUI.EXE](http://www.sqlshack.com/ways-use-execute-sql-server-integration-services-packages/) although you'd need to [install SSIS](http://goo.gl/h3uADe) from original media files locallly

Comment: Thanks, I added a project so that the dtsx was inside there, now I can run it